# Select the index of a random non-zero element in list in Matlab

Tags: list, matlab

Is there any ready command to get the intended output from the input?

**Input**

```
>>> a=[1 0 3 0 5 6 7 8 0 10 0 0]; selectNonZero(a)
```

**Intended output**

```
1 or 3 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 10
```

**Trials**

```
>> b=a(a~=0); pi=randi([1, length(b)]); b(pi)    % The original index of b(pi)?

>> fix=[0 1 2 2 2 2 2]; pi+fix(pi)               % Fix changed index, cum command?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variant of Luis' answer is to use the built-in [`nnz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html) function:

```
idx = find(a);
rand_idx = idx(randi(nnz(a)));
```

If you have the Statistics Toolbox installed, you can reduce this into a one-liner using [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html):

```
rand_idx = randsample(find(a), 1);
```

Note: if you want to choose a random value (and not its index), replace `find(a)` with `nonzeros(a)` (this is a shorter alternative to generating a random index and then  doing `a(rand_idx)`).

Comment: Always with the simplest ^-^ +1

Comment: @hhh I didn't read the title of the question thoroughly; my solution picked a random non-zero *value* from vector `a`, not its index. However, I've modified it to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way. It's similar to your approach, but using `find` to know the indices of nonzero values.

```
jj = find(a~=0); % indices of nonzero values of a
ind = jj(randi(length(jj))); % randomly pick one of those indices
val = a(ind); % corresponding value of a
```

The results you want are `sel` (selected value) and `ind` (its index within `a`).

Comment: It does not do the thing -- notice that I want to get the original index, not the original value. I want that it returns some index where the corresponding value is non-zero -- I thought about looping and checking for the non-zero but in my situation too much overheat.

Comment: @hhh Welcome! And thanks for your edit. I was at the same time doing more or less the same modification :-)